# Where clause in SQL Query skip date filter when date is null

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have search query with parameters are Name, From date, To date. When i pass empty string or null to date parameters it should return all data matches with name only. This code is not working for me.

```
WHERE name=@name 
AND 
(CASE WHEN @_from IS not null 
            THEN
                Servicedate<=@_from 
            END)
```

This is also not woking for me.

```
WHERE name = @name AND
Servicedate>=ISNULL((case when @_from='' then NULL else @_from),Servicedate)
```

Thank You.

Comment: Is it mysql or sql-server. That are two very different DBMS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this:

```
WHERE
    name = @name
    AND (@_from IS NULL OR ServiceDate >= @_from)
    AND (@_to IS NULL OR ServiceDate <= @_to)
```

If the variables(`@_from` and `@_to`) are unset, the condition will return `true` since `@var IS NULL` is `true`.

Answer (score 1):

```
WHERE ( name=@name AND @_from IS NOT NULL AND Servicedate<=@_from )
      OR
      ( name=@name AND @_from IS null )
```

If date parameter `@_from` is empty then searching is done only on name parameter `@name` else `ServiceDate` column is matched against date parameter `@_from`

Answer (score 1):

```
WHERE
(name=@name AND @_from IS NOT NULL AND @_from <> '' AND Servicedate<=@_from )
OR
(name=@name AND (@_from IS null or @_from = ''))
```